# Drawing a PolyLine with DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I have a Shape witch draws a Line dependent on a ObservableCollection of Nodes (Angles and Factors) around the center.

The DefiningGeometry override looks like this:

```
            PolyLineSegment curve = new PolyLineSegment(this.Nodes.Select(NodeToPoint), true);
            PolyLineSegment bounds = new PolyLineSegment(
                new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, GeometrySize), new Point(GeometrySize, GeometrySize), new Point(GeometrySize, 0) }, false);

            PathFigureCollection figures = new PathFigureCollection(new[]
            {
                new PathFigure(NodeToPoint(this.Nodes[this.Nodes.Count - 1]), new[] { curve }, false),
                new PathFigure(new Point(0, 0), new[] { bounds }, false)
            });

            return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.Nonzero, null);
```

If a Node Factor or the Collection changes i invoke InvalidateVisual. 
And here is the Problem if i have some more of this Shapes on a Window which cross each other processor load pops up to 25% (On a QuadCore ofc) if i change Factors frequently.

What is the correct approach to draw a frequently updated LineSegment collection?
Is Shape the right Component to do this. ? Maybe my approach is totally wrong but i am stuck here.

EDIT:
I Updated the Code to the following:

`protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get { return this.curveGeometry ?? EmptyBounds; }
        }`

And the The PropertyChangedHandler to the following

```
  private void NodePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Node node = sender as Node;
        if (node != null && this.indexMapping.ContainsKey(node) && this.indexMapping[node] != -1)
        {  
            this.UpdatePoint(node);
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePoint(Node node)
    {
        if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Node>(UpdatePoint), node);
        else
        {
            this.curve.Points[this.indexMapping[node]] = NodeToPoint(node);
            this.InvalidateVisual();    
        }
    }
```

as stated in the comments the code does not work if i don't call InvalidateVisual. The Problem remains if i add 5 curves with an overall of 1000 nodes the processor load starts to increase if the lines Cross each other and i change a single value.

I will take a look at some processor sampling and report back.

Comment: did you profile your code? use WPF performance suite it will give you some clues.on which visusal do you run the InvalidateVisual?

Comment: You might optimize this by not re-creating the whole PathGeometry each time a single polyline point changes. Just update the appropriate PolyLineSegment or PathFigure.

Comment: @Clemens if i recalculate the point in my PropertyChanged event do i need to InvalidateVisual anyway? or does the Geometry invalidate the modified region by itself?

Comment: I guess it should do that. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work, i think the shape is the wrong class to encapsulate what i try.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to create a new geometry each time the data changes. The following simplified example (without MVVM) shows that the UI is updated by only changing a Point in a PolyLineSegment in a PathGeometry:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="geometry"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PolyLineSegment segment;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        segment = new PolyLineSegment();
        segment.IsStroked = true;
        segment.Points.Add(new Point(100, 100));
        segment.Points.Add(new Point(200, 200));

        var figure = new PathFigure { StartPoint = new Point(0, 0) };
        figure.Segments.Add(segment);

        geometry.Figures.Add(figure);
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        segment.Points[0] = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i change a point of my segment in a shape the VisualOutput is not Updated, i added my current approach to the OP.

Comment: Why do you need a derived Shape at all? A Path sould be sufficient.

Comment: I don't, i just tried this out, will change it to a usercontrol which simply contains the path.

Comment: I changed the Control to a ContentControl containing a Path which data i set in the code behind. But it didn't change anything, maybe i hit the limitations of PathGeometry here and i need to go to SteamgGeometry to increase Performance, i will keep it like that for the moment.